# Allow one or zero matches in regex, but prefer one

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-greedy

I want to match a query parameter in a url string, for example `?foo=bar&para=val`.
I need a regex pattern that looks if there is a `foo` parameter and returns it's value. If there is no match return an empty string.
I tried this pattern: `/(?:foo=([^&]+))?/` but it returns an empty match. It returns the value if I change it to `/(foo=([^&]+))+/`

**expected results:**

- `?foo=myvalue&bar=bazz` should return `myvalue`
- `?bar=bazz` should return `(empty string)`

Any ideas?

Comment: What language? Could you provide some input samples and expected result?

Comment: Edited. language is php

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: @andy-lester I'd love to avoid regex but I need to use it in `RewriteCond`

Comment: The language is `.htaccess`. **Not PHP.**

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\w)foo=([^&]*)|
```

Simply doing this should be enough.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/18

Comment: Please be aware that this would include `?notfoo=bar`.

Comment: but in the second case there is no match. I want a match and an empty string to be returned.

Comment: The problem is that I don't think I can use the `g` flag in .htaccess

Comment: You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* match it with regex, why not use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str)?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://domain.com?foo=bar&bar=foo&rab=oof&oof=rab';

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);

if (!empty($params)) {
    print_r($params);
    /*
        Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
            [bar] => foo
            [rab] => oof
            [oof] => rab
        )
    */

    if (isset($params['foo'])) {
        var_dump($params['foo']); // string(3) "bar"
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/4TiKeX6L)

Comment: because it's to be used in `RewriteCond` in .htaccess file

Comment: @tamir Then the language is not `.php`. It's `.htaccess`. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: Well his question has a lot value to me. So sad the actual question hasnt been answered.

Comment: @C4u OP's question made no sense in terms of his question. It was an obvious XY problem. Please read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Have you tried looking at lazy/greedy matching in regex?

Comment: Maybe the question should be edited then? I mean, at least for myself, this was misleading. Capturing one character 0 or 1 times with prefering 1 seems to be a problem. Anyway, I wont take any actions in here. Someone else can decide about it. Just wanted to leave a comment that I got misleaded and left open with my problem due to the questions title. Wrong place to discuss my actual problem :). I'll get around it. Ty

Answer (score 0):

if your tool/language supported look behind, you could try:

```
(?<=[?&]foo=)[^&]*
```